# Google Sheets: Copy range / row to another sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to copy the row from "Sheet1" to "Sheet2".

However, the row number will depend on the value in A2 on Sheet1
If A2 has 3, I want to copy to row 3 in Sheet2.
Similarly, if it has 15, I want to copy to row 15 in Sheet2.

I have tried to do the following code to copy

```
function copyTo() {
    let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
    let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
    sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(1, 1));
}
```

What this does is copy row 2 in Sheet1 to row 2 of Sheet2, regardless of the value in Cell A2 of Sheet1.

How can I make this work to copy to the specific row I want?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function copyTo() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(sourceSheet.getRange("A2").getValue() || 1, 1)); // Modified
}
```

- In this modification, the values of `sourceRange` is copied to the row retrieved from "A2" of "Sheet1".

Comment: Hi @Tanaike! That works a treat. Follow up question after making that work:
What if I want to just copy rows 3:5? I tried 
        let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange("3:5");
But that didn't work

Comment: @George Thank you for replying. From `That works a treat.`, I understood that your question was resolved. About your new question of `Follow up question after making that work: What if I want to just copy rows 3:5? I tried let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange("3:5"); But that didn't work`, in this case, please modify `let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();` to `let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange("3:5");`.

Comment: @George Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.